# Getting Parse error and syntax error how to solve this?

Tags: wordpress, syntax-error, parse-error

How can i resolve this, running this code getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'get_post_meta' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';', the code is

```
   <?php
                $all_terms=get_terms('filtering_category', 
                  array(
                  'hide_empty' => false
                    ));

                foreach($all_terms as $single_term)
                { echo ' <li class="'get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'serv_active', true);'"><a href="#'.$single_term-> slug.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$single_term-> name.'</a>
              </li>';
                }  
?>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$all_terms = get_terms( 'filtering_category', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

foreach( $all_terms as $single_term ) {
    echo '<li class="' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'serv_active', true ) . '"><a href="#' . $single_term-> slug . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $single_term-> name . '</a></li>';
}
```

You were missing concatenation in your echoed string - `echo $var . 'string' . $other_var` 
Notice the dots ([concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)).

Comment: Happy to help :)